# Breakpoint hit for angular js code but not for jquery code - VS2013

Tags: jquery, angularjs, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am facing a strange issue when debugging my application in IE / Chrome. I have mix of Angular JS code and jQuery JS files in my project. The break point on Angular JS code is successfully hit. But the breakpoint in jQuery doesn't get hit. I see a message in VS2013 - the breakpoint will not currently be hit no symbols loaded for this document.
if I place debugger in the code in jQuery files, the break point is hit and I am able to debug inside the browser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: any thoughts on this issue?